# Getting text of Radio in Ant.desing and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using [Ant Desing Radio](https://ant.design/components/radio/) with react js for creating a radio button. and i create a Radio button like this with map function :

```
<RadioGroup onChange={this.setActivityType}  defaultValue={this.props.activityTypes[0].value} size="large">

                {this.props.activityTypes.map((type,i)=>(
                      <RadioButton key={i} value={type.value} >{type.name}</RadioButton>
                ))}
</RadioGroup>
```

also in `onChange={this.setActivityType}` function i can see `e.target.value` that is passed as `value={type.value}` i also need name of between tag of `<RadioButton>` , the `{type.name}` but i can't see any properties in developer tools or antd docs ? dose anyone know how to access this property and save it to state with onChange?

Comment: try this: define a name property with each `RadioButton` like this: `<RadioButton key={i} value={type.value} name={type.name}>{type.name}</RadioButton>` then try to access that name inside onChange method by `e.target.name`.

Comment: yes , that's correct

Comment: added that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the name of each `RadioButton` define a name property with each `RadioButton` like this:

```
<RadioButton key={i} value={type.value} name={type.name}>{type.name}</RadioButton>
```

Now inside `onChange` method access that name by `e.target.name`.